# CX_freeze with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, cx-freeze, ruamel.yaml

I can't get CX_Freeze to include the package ruamel.yaml with the build_exe.

I've also tried adding it to the "packages" option like

```
build_exe_options = {
    ...
    "packages": [
        ...
        "ruamel.yaml",
        ...
    ]
    ...
}
cx_Freeze.setup(
    ...
    executables=[cx_Freeze.Executable("pyhathiprep/__main__.py",
                                  targetName="pyhathiprep.exe", base="Console")],
)
```

and I get

```
File "C:\Users\hborcher\PycharmProjects\pyhathiprep\.env\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 350, in _ImportModule
raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name)
ImportError: No module named 'ruamel.yaml'
```

I've tried adding it to the "namespace_packages" like

```
build_exe_options = {
    ...
    "namespace_packages": ["ruamel.yaml"]
    ...
}
cx_Freeze.setup(
    ...
    executables=[cx_Freeze.Executable("pyhathiprep/__main__.py",
                                  targetName="pyhathiprep.exe", base="Console")],
)
```

and I get

```
File "C:\Users\hborcher\PycharmProjects\pyhathiprep\.env\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 221, in _FindModule
return None, module.__path__[0], info
TypeError: '_NamespacePath' object does not support indexing
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried importing as `"packages": ["ruamel"]`?

Comment: Yeah. it gives me the exception message "ImportError: No module named 'ruamel'"

Comment: @loneraver which is to be expected as there is no package `ruamel` on PyPI

Comment: @Anthon, yup! I was pulling my hair out trying to figure it out so I was at the point where I'd try anything. So I tried it anyways. Even though I know you are the maintainer, I can verify that you are correct. :-)

Comment: I tried searching for `pyhathiprep`, to try and see what you are doing and found exactly **one** result on Google.

Answer (score 1):

The `doc` for `ruamel.yaml` clearly states that you have to use a recent version of `pip` and `setuptools` to install `ruamel.yaml`.

CX_Freeze is not calling `pip`, nor does it support installing from the (correctly pre-configured) `.whl` files. Instead it does seem to call `setup()` in a way of its own.

What you can try to do is create a `ruamel` directory in your source directory, then in that directory create an empty `__init__.py` file and `yaml` directory. In that `yaml` directory copy all of the `.py` files from an unpacked [latest version of `ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/packages/78/c7/413f5c3a4efd0aeb14d37dc03427574571db5060058e32963dc2d7d21ff0/ruamel.yaml-0.15.21.tar.gz#md5=06b2dee49c14fa3a7bf01d576babd5f6) skipping `setup.py` and all of the other install cruft. Alternatively you can check those files out from [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src), but then there is even more unnecessary cruft to deal with, and you run the slight risk of having a non-released intermediate version if you don't check out by release tag.
Once that works you'll have a "pure" Python version of `ruamel.yaml` in your frozen application.

If you are using `yaml = YAML(typ='safe')` or `yaml = YAML(typ='unsafe')` and you expect the speed up from the C based loader and dumper, then you should look at using the Windows `.whl` files provided on PyPI. They include the `_ruamel_yaml.cpXY-win_NNN.pyd` files. If you don't know your target (python and/or win32|win_amd64 you should be able to include all of them and `ruamel.yaml` will pick the right one when it starts (actually it only does `from _ruamel_yaml import CParser, CEmitter` and assumes the Python interpreter knows what to do).

Comment: I have the most recent version of pip and setuptools and that's how I installed it. It works when I use it normally. I think I just figured out a hack to get it to freeze. I'll post it in a second once I can verify that I can reproduced it.

Comment: I just looked at the CX_freeze docs and you might be able to just do `os.system("pip install ruamel.yaml")` from your `setup.py` file

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out a solution. I think it might be a bug in CX_Freeze. If I pip install ruamel.base and ruamel.yaml cx_freeze seems to install everything correctly. This is true, even if I ask it to only include ruamel.yaml.

If I have both ruamel.base and ruamel.yaml installed, then this works...

```
build_exe_options = {
    ...
    "namespace_packages": ["ruamel.yaml"]
    ...
}
cx_Freeze.setup(
    ...
    executables=[cx_Freeze.Executable("pyhathiprep/__main__.py",
                              targetName="pyhathiprep.exe", base="Console")],
)
```

Comment: `ruamel.base` provides an `__init__.py` file in the directory `ruamel`, and that is probably what enables CX_freeze to load. Are you really installing in your normal environment and the running `python setup.py build`? Or did you add `ruamel.base` to the `setup.py`

Comment: Because the IT department here requires that I deliver everything as a  bundled .msi installer (hence the cx_freeze), I have 2 setup.py. First, I have a normal setup.py which uses setuptools, which makes development very nice with Tox and etc. Second, I also have a cx_setup.py which creates the .msi standalone distribution version. The normal setuptools setup.py didn't need ruamel.base explicitly added to install ruamel.yaml.

Comment: Maybe you can show the packages (that includes `ruamel.base`, as part of your working version here as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with azure. The issue is the way microsoft structured the azure package - you can import azure.something.something_else.module, but you can't import azure directly. cx_freeze needs to be able to find the folder azure (or in your case, the folder ruamel) directly, not just the subfolders.

I had to go to each directory under the azure folder that I was accessing and ensure there was an **init**.py file there. After that, cx_freeze was able to find it perfectly.

Another option would be to just directly copy the folder from a path that you know (direct link to your site-packages, or copy the ruamel directory into your program directory and copy it from there) into the build folder as part of your setup. I do this for things like my data files:

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree("icons","build/exe.win32-3.6/icons")
```